# Strain gauge in a voltage divider

Tags: voltage-divider, strain-gage

I have a strain gauge mounted in a voltage divider as in the image below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm9ate.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

where \$R_{g}\$ is the resistance of the strain gauge when it is not strained (120 \$\Omega\$), \$R\$ is a 1200 \$\Omega\$ resistor, \$V_{app}\$ is the voltage applied on the voltage divider (1.1 V) and \$V_{meas}\$ is the voltage measured with a lock-in amplifier.

When the strain gauge is not strained, \$V_{meas}= V_{1} = \frac{R_{g}}{R+R_{g}}*V_{app} = 0.1 V\$

How to calculate \$V_{meas}\$ when the strain gauge is strained?

This is a shortened version of my question. The original formulation is hidden behind the spoiler.

> The strain across the strain gauge is \$x = \frac{1}{GF} * \frac{\Delta R_{g}}{Rg}\$ (eq. 2) where GF is the gauge factor. I am not certain how to express \$x\$ as a function of \$V_{meas}\$. So far, I used the following method:
>  when the strain gauge is strained, eq. 1 becomes: \$V_{meas} = V_{2} = \frac{R_{g}+\Delta R_{g}}{R+R_{g}+\Delta R_{g}}*V_{app}\$.
>  From there I get \$\frac{\Delta R_{g}}{R} = - \frac{R}{\Delta R_{g}} * \frac{V_{2}}{V_{2}-V_{app}} - 1\$ (eq. 3).
>  By inserting eq. 3 in eq. 2, I have \$x = - \frac{1}{GF} * (\frac{R}{\Delta R_{g}} * \frac{V_{2}}{V_{2}-V_{app}} + 1)\$ (eq. 4).
>  Using eq. 1, I get \$\frac{R}{R_{g}} = \frac{V_{app}-V_{1}}{V_{1}}\$ and inserting this equation in eq. 4:
>  \$x = - \frac{1}{GF} * (\frac{V_{app}-V_{1}}{V_{1}} * \frac{V_{2}}{V_{2}-V_{app}} + 1)\$.
>  Knowing the values of \$V_{app}\$ and \$V_{1}\$, I obtain: \$x = - \frac{1}{GF} * (10*\frac{V_{2}}{V_{2}-1.1} + 1)\$ where \$V_{2}\$ is the voltage measured with the lock-in amplifier when the strain gauge is strained.
>  Could someone confirm these equations? Thank you!

Comment: I think your pursuit for the eventual correct answer may be simply theoretical, but eventually you will require to calibrate and obtain real-world measurements to correlate the strain with the output voltage. Wouldn't it be simpler (given you have the right equipment) to apply a known strain and measure the voltage and so calibrate your system as it would behave ? Then you may also be able to confirm the theoretical part of your problem ... just a thought ...that is, is this part of a real working circuit or an engineering assignement ?

Comment: @citizen No, this is not a theoretical question, it is already implemented in a setup. I cannot calibrate the system with a known strain. The strain gauge is on a silicon wafer mechanically fixed on its edge and strained by compressed air. The voltage measured across the strain gauge is sent to a LabView program and I need to calculate the strain in the program.